# inspect for functions starting _

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect

I looking at a functions from pyasl module.

```
from PyAstronomy import pyasl
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(pyasl.get_lagrange_1))
```

which shows that the function returns:

```
return _get_lagrange_123(q, eps, 1-eps, getdlrp)
```

How to see the function starting with _, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it has a leading `_`, you need to import it explicitly and then inspect it. From the github repo, it seems that `_get_lagrange_123` is defined in `src/pyasl/asl/aslExt_1/roche.py`, so you might be able to import it using

```py
from PyAstronomy.pyasl.asl.aslExt_1.roche import _get_lagrange_123
print(inspect.getsource(_get_lagrange_123))
```

Although I don't have this library `PyAstronomy` so I can't check it. In any case, you first need to find where the function `_get_lagrange_123` is defined and then import the function from the module explicitly.

Comment: It must be `from PyAstronomy.pyasl import _get_lagrange_123`?

Comment: I got an error: >>> from PyAstronomy.pyasl import _get_lagrange_123
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_lagrange_123'`

Comment: Can you check `from PyAstronomy.pyasl.asl.aslExt_1.roche import _get_lagrange_123`?